# Rubber plant dying need help

Tags: houseplants

[image]!

Need advice. It started with leaves drooping. As you can see there are 3 stems. Only one seems to be drooping. The weight got too heavy and the stem is now bent and thin. Is there anyway i could save it?

Without needing a paper clip to support it with the healthy stem. Am i over or under watering? [image]